# setuptools.package-data has no effect within a docker container

Tags: python, setuptools, pyproject.toml

So, I have this little pyproject.toml-based project (named `RecordEcos`) to do multi-camera recording with a minimalist interface (using PySimpleGUI). The interface make use of a placeholder image when the camera are not connected.

I've added the following section to my pyproject.toml to ensure the image is well embedded into the wheel.

```ini
[tool.setuptools.package-data]
RecordEcos = ["*.png"]
```

And indeed, everything works perfectly on my laptop:

```bash
$ python -m build | grep Placeholder
copying RecordEcos/gui/img/Placeholder.png -> RecordEcos-0.4.5/RecordEcos/gui/img
copying RecordEcos/gui/img/Placeholder.png -> build/lib/RecordEcos/gui/img
copying build/lib/RecordEcos/gui/img/Placeholder.png -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/RecordEcos/gui/img
adding 'RecordEcos/gui/img/Placeholder.png'
```

Actually, it's working on my laptop even if I don't add the setuptools `package-data` option. Which seems to be quite consonant with setuptools [documentation](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html#package-data).

So I've pushed it to gitlab, the CI has been triggered... And the resulting wheel does not contains the image.
So to be sure, I've try it within a docker image:

```bash
laptop $ docker run -it python:3.11 /bin/bash
python-container $ pip install build
python-container $ git clone <repository>
python-container $ cd <repository>
python-container & python -m build | grep Placeholder
```

The image is not copied !

Does someone have any clue what's happening there ?

I've tried it with the alpine, slim and bookworm variants of `python:3.11`

##### Misc informations

laptop under ArchLinux

**Python & packages**
Python: 3.11.8
build: 1.1.1
setuptools: 65.6.0

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  image: python:3.11-alpine
  script:
    - pip install build
    - python -m build
  artifacts:
    untracked: false
    when: on_success
    expire_in: "30 days"
    paths:
      - dist/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this for a fact, but I believe you either need to explicitly call out the package_data argument, or you need to setup a Manifest file.

[image]
https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/miscellaneous.html#using-manifest-in

Comment: Using `MANIFEST.in` did the trick, ty ! But I still don't understand why It was working on my laptop without the manifest... If a future reader came across this post, do not hesitate to necrobump, I'm quite curious about this behavior !